# "strongly" or "strong"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs

Is *strongly* correct in the following, or should it be *strong*?

> ... and had a strongly Protestant and unionist identity.

What is the explanation in grammar terms?

[Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ireland_and_World_War_I#Unionist_response).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct, but *strong* is a bit better.

- *Strong Protestant and unionist identity* says that the 36th Division had a Protestant and unionist identity, and that sense of collective identity was intense.
- *Strongly Protestant and unionist identity* says that the 36th Division had a sense of identity, and that identity was intensely Protestant and unionist in character.

The difference is subtle. I think both statements are accurate, but the former is closer to what the article means to say. So *strong* is the right word to use.

Martha says that *strong Protestant and unionist identity* is strictly speaking incorrect unless you add commas. I disagree. It’s completely standard. It is easy to find plenty of examples of this pattern in good journalism and academic writing. Here are some examples (found in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)):

> *strong economic and political ties*
>
> *a strong moral and ethical impulse*
>
> *an Iranian culture with strong Hellenistic and Indian traditions*
>
> *complex social and economic conditions*
>
> *overall physical and mental health*
>
> *alternating hot and cold water*

There are thousands more.
The pattern also appears in the name of the [National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration](http://www.noaa.gov/), a U.S. government agency.

Answer (score 5):

"Strongly" is okay in this sentence. To help clarify:

> It had a [strongly Protestant and unionist] identity.

"Strongly" is modifying "Protestant and unionist" to compare it against a mildly Protestant/union identity. Using "strong" would change the meaning and require some fiddling:

> It had a strong, Protestant, unionist identity.

Here, we could remove the last two adjectives:

> It had a strong identity.

The possible source of confusion is the "and" between "Protestant" and "unionist":

> It had a strongly Protestant identity.

This probably sounds less awkward.

Answer (score 5):

*Strongly* is correct. In grammatical terms, *strongly* is an **adverb** modifying, in this case, the **adjectives** *Protestant* and *unionist*, which are in turn modifying the **noun** *identity*.

There is a tendency in modern English to use adjectives as adverbs, resulting in things like "*... a strong Protestant and unionist identity...*", but strictly speaking this is incorrect, unless you add commas to make the adjective modify the noun instead: "*... a strong, Protestant, and unionist identity...*" — but obviously the latter means something quite different than the version without commas.

That said, unless you're writing for a particularly nitpicky audience, either choice is fine and will be understood as an adverb (unless marked as an adjective).